# Given string to object convert

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, object

I have to current string taken from

```
<div id="someif" array-data="2012-03-01:1,2012-03-11:1,2012-03-21:1"></div>
var mystring={2012-03-01:1,2012-03-11:1,2012-03-21:1}
```

and need this js object created

```
var dates_allowed = {
      '2012-03-01': 1,
      '2012-03-11': 1,
      '2012-03-21': 13
};
```

i have tried with but no result - i get error

```
jQuery.parseJSON(myString);
```

Thanks!

Comment: `array-data`? better if you write `data-array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

Working with your current HTML, you could do something like this:

```
var dates_allowed = {};

$('#someif').attr('array-data').split(',').each(function(){
    var date = this.split(',');
    dates_allowed[date[0]] = date[1];
});
```

**Better solution**

But in my opinion you'd be better off leveraging [jQuery data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) by changing your HTML to something like:

```
<div id="someif" data-dates="{&quot;2012-03-01&quot;:1,&quot;2012-03-11&quot;:1,&quot;2012-03-21&quot;:1}"></div>
```

And using the following JavaScript:

```
var dates_allowed = $('#someif').data('dates');
```

[scessor's example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yALyS/).

Comment: var dates_allowed = $('#someif').data('dates');
value is undefined

Comment: Your 'better solution' will return an string, because the single quotes aren't json valid string wrapper (see [json documentation](http://www.json.org/)). Change them to double quotes with `&quote;`. Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/yALyS/). And integer values don't need to be in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't parse a string like '2012-03-01:1,2012-03-11:1,2012-03-21:1' with JSON

This string would be parseable:

```
'[{"allowed":"2012-03-01","index":"1"}, {"allowed":"2012-03-11","index":"1"},{"allowed":"2012-03-21","index":"1"}]'
```

So, used as [data attribute](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/)

```
<div id="someif" data-allowed='[{"allowed":"2012-03-01","index":"1"}, {"allowed":"2012-03-11","index":"1"},{"allowed":"2012-03-21","index":"1"}]'>

var myAllowedDates = JSON.parse($('#someif').attr('data-allowed'));
```

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/bTKzG/)